# Discord.js How do i tagg a user when he joining the server?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
channel.send("Hello", WelcomeEmbed);
```

I want the bot to send `"Hello"` then tag the user that join and send my `Embed`.

This code almost works how I want, but it doesn't tag the person obviously.

I tried a couple of things but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the user's `User` or `GuildMember` object in a string, it will mention them.

```js
channel.send(`Hello ${member}`, WelcomeEmbed);
```

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SO. If an answer solves your question you should accept it, this lets others know the question has been answered and also lets people looking for answers know what worked